# Parse string to integer in arbitrary base/radix

Tags: perl, integer, radix, string-parsing, parseint

In other languages besides Perl, if I want to parse a string representing a number in a weird, non-standard base (not necessarily the normal binary (2), octal (8), decimal (10), or hexadecimal (16) bases), or the base must be determined programmatically at runtime, converting from string to integer in said base is pretty simple, so long as the base is between 2 and 36 (where bases above 10 use `a-z` and/or `A-Z` to represent the larger digits), e.g., to parse `"JQ"` in base-34, getting `672` as the result, I can do:

```py
int("JQ", 34)  # Python
```

```js
parseInt("JQ", 34);  // JavaScript
```

```cpp
strtol("JQ", NULL, 34);     // C or C++, also strtoul, strtoll, strtoull
std::stol("JQ", NULL, 34);  // C++-only, best when first argument already a std::string, similar options as strto*
```

```bash
$((34#JQ))  # Even bash can do it with built-in functionality
```

**Is there a built-in way to do this string-to-integer parsing, with arbitrary bases (ideally able to be provided at runtime) in Perl that doesn't rely on third-party modules, and doesn't involve me writing a ton of code to reinvent the wheel?** (I'm not looking for anything that involves manually looping to convert digit-by-digit and multiply into a final value; that's long, tedious, error-prone, and reinventing the wheel)

I figure if the answer is "No", if nothing else I can cheat by having `bash` do the work for me with backticks or the like, but it feels kind of weird that Perl, alone among common languages, including languages with similar designs and application (e.g. Ruby, PHP, `bash`), is missing this functionality.

Comment: In core, there's `Math::BigInt->from_base`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to execute a shell just to parse a number in an arbitrary base. The standard (Not third-party) [`POSIX` module](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX) provides the [`strtol()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX#strtol) function, which, just like the C version it's a wrapper for, lets you specify a base between 2 and 36:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use POSIX;

say scalar POSIX::strtol("JQ", 34);
```

The thing that needs remembering so it doesn't cause issues is that it returns a two-element list in list context (The converted number and the count of trailing characters not part of it), and just the converted number in scalar context.

Comment: Awesome. That's most directly what I was looking for. Not great for code golf (which is where this need came up), but I've needed to parse in arbitrary bases for real reasons before, and I was a little bothered by not being able to find an obvious solution for Perl.

Comment: Why would you be bothered? It's a super rare thing to want to do. It shouldn't be built in. You should have be bothered if it was built in. That's exactly what modules are for. Even base64-encoding (which *is* commonly used) is provided by a module, not built in.

Comment: @ikegami: I'll grant parsing *arbitrary* bases is uncommon. But parsing in runtime determined bases rather than constant bases is not unreasonable; if the data source is a mixed of tagged decimal, octal and hex, it'd be nice to just be able to either key off the prefix (with `base` of `0`) or if identified from side-band data, pass the known base, rather than dynamically selecting between different functions, e.g. relying on weak-typing for string->decimal int conversion, `hex` for hex, `oct` for octal. It's fine to have it in a built-in module, it doesn't need to pollute global namespace.

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question, most languages provide this functionality in a pretty obvious way. It's not that you regularly need to parse it in weird ways, it's that the APIs allow it without any particular added complexity, so why *not* provide it? Even JavaScript, which, like Perl, has less need for explicit type-conversion to/from string/integer due to the weak-typing provides `parseInt` as a global function. I do consider it "built-in" even when it's just in core modules, so I'm not criticizing Perl here for failing to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Re "*most languages provide this functionality in a pretty obvious way*", That's not a an valid argument

Comment: Re "*if the data source is a mixed of tagged decimal, octal and hex*",  There are plenty of builtin tools for those.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in way.

(And module recommendations, third-party or otherwise, are off-topic.)

Comment: `\`echo \$(($base#$str))\`` it is, I guess (assuming I don't care about Windows anyway).

Comment: That doesn't work because backticks use `sh`, and that's not a feature of the POSIX shell. (`sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "34#JQ"`)

Comment: Yep, just discovered that. It *does* work when the underlying `sh` is really `bash` (my local workstation handled it), but not when `sh` is separate (as on the Alpine image I was testing on). That system does *have* `bash`, so `\`bash -c 'echo \$(($base#$str))'\`` works, but ugh, that's awful.